# Display images inside table in Vue JS along with base url (Laravel 5.2)

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vue-resource

Well, I am able to display the images properly but it is still giving me javascript errors in console for no reason. Here is my code:

Fetching categories:

```
fetchCategory: function(){

            this.$http.get('get_category').then(function(response){
                this.$set('categories',response.json());
            });
        }
```

and here is the table to display the category:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-striped example1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Category Name</th>
            <th>Icon</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="category in categories">
            <td>@{{ category.id }}</td>
            <td>@{{ category.name }}</td>
            <td><img src="{{url('/')}}/@{{ category.icon }}" width="150px"></td>
            <td>Edit | Delete</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

it displays the images properly, however javascript console still shows 2 404 errors indicating the url of the image 
GET http://localhost/project/%7B%7B%20category.icon%20%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)

Should I ignore this error?
Or is there any other method to include base url in the image path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should bind the `src` attribute:

```
<img :src="'{{ url('/') }}/' + category.icon" width="150px">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<td>{!!HTML::image('path/category.icon')!!}</td>
```

Comment: category is a Vue object, can't be used like that.

Comment: But you used in blading and what is the value of category.icon?

Comment: category.icon gives a relative path like assets/images/categories/TOOZ6xW8V2JA.jpg

It is displaying corretly, but is showing 404 error in console as well